# How to validate the given address using USPS?

Tags: c#

I want to validate the given address (address, city, state, zip) to the USPS and return back the result if the provided address is a valid address. and if it is not the valid address returns the invalid address.

so how can i do this in C#.Net.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USPS_Web_Tools_Wrapper.aspx)

```
///Create a new instance of the USPS Manager class
///The constructor takes 2 arguments, the first is
///your USPS Web Tools User ID and the second is 
///true if you want to use the USPS Test Servers.
USPSManager m = new USPSManager("YOUR_USER_ID", true);
Address a = new Address();
a.Address2 = "6406 Ivy Lane";
a.City = "Greenbelt";
a.State = "MD";

///By calling ValidateAddress on the USPSManager object,
///you get an Address object that has been validated by the
///USPS servers
Address validatedAddress = m.ValidateAddress(a);
```

**NOTE**: For some reason, you need to put the actual Address as Address2. If you attempt to put Address1 as "6406 Ivy Lane" it will fail. Address1 is apparently for apartment or suite number. *Courtesy [Simon Weaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16940/simon-weaver)'s comment below*.

Comment: IMPORTANT: For some stupid reason you need to put the actual Address as Address2. If you attempt to put Address1 as "6406 Ivy Lane" it will fail. Address1 is apparently for apartment or suite number : https://www.usps.com/webtools/_pdf/Address-Information-v3-1b.pdf

Comment: Wow! 8 years later and the API has literally not changed at all. All the same old problems :-( Another super annoying thing is whether you specify an apartment number incorrectly, or not at all you get the same exact error message.

Comment: Tip: If you implement an address verification system, use REAL addresses that REAL customers enter to test the flow. I've implemented our new system to give me a random customer's address when I open the page - so I can get a really good impression as to how the experience goes for a real customer. I have 10 years worth of user input to draw on. You'll also find lots of edge cases with this - as well as limitations with USPS system (or whatever you use). Just be sure that it's impossible for this feature to be deployed to production!

Comment: @lospolloshermanos sorry I added unnecessary confusion. I couldn't remember myself what I meant. What I actually did during development was to randomly load a REAL customer address from my database into my checkout address form. So a different customer each time I refreshed the page. 1) Saves me time entering an address each time. 2) Allowed me to see what the actual experience was going to be for real customer data and make adjustments to make it make more sense.

Answer (score 14):

The United States Postal Service (USPS) does offer this service via their Address Information APIs:

- [USPS: Ecommerce APIs](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm)

Here's a Code Project article/library how you could use this services in .NET:

- [United States Postal Service (USPS) Web Tools Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/USPS_Web_Tools_Wrapper.aspx)

**Note**

- Before you can use this library, you will need to get a USPS Web Tools ID by filling out this [form](https://secure.shippingapis.com/registration/).
- To request the Address Informational APIs (Verify etc.) you need additional permissions. Also fill out this [form](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-address-information.htm) to apply for these permissions.

Comment: i have used the code project example but if i am passing the test mode value to false i am getting as Authorization is required. how can i resolve that issue

Comment: Did you register for a USPS Web Tools ID? https://secure.shippingapis.com/registration/

Comment: i am passing the Web Tools ID and it is getting the error as "API Authorization failure. User XXXXXXXX is not authorized to use API Verify." why i am getting this error?

Comment: @Vara Prasad.M: As the error says you are not authorized for the Verify API. I made an update to my answer.

Comment: I have registered in the form by sending the Web Tool Id and the site that i am using the API provided and also i received the mail from ICCC that my profile has been allowed to access the secure site. but if i am changing the test mode to false and placing the same user id and the urls i am setting as ProductionUrl = "http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll
 
";
TestingUrl = "https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll
 
"
user id =XXXXXXXXXX
testing mode =false

Comment: The above USPS links are "File or Page Requested Not Found". Would you please fix the links to the right pages?

Comment: 2nd link broken again.

Answer (score 6):

If I may chime in here -- I used to work in the address validation industry for SmartyStreets, which is a CASS-Certified vendor of these services.

Note first that, while the USPS is the authority on address data, *their forte is NOT maintaining an API and providing support.* Also, be sure to note the agreement which you signed:

> - User agrees to use the USPS Web site, APIs and USPS data to facilitate USPS shipping transactions only.

So unless you're mailing or shipping with the USPS by the use of their API, it's not agreeable to use the API at all. This among the other problems you're having is grounds to look for a better solution -- if I was you.

Anyway, there are actually quite a few out there. I'll let you do your own research, but of course I would suggest one that I've worked on called LiveAddress. It's free, and returns more data and is more reliable than the USPS' API.

**Update:** [Here's some C# code examples on GitHub](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/c-sharp) that will probably be useful.

Comment: Something of note regarding valid use of the USPS API, there is a service called TaxCloud that verifies addresses based on the USPS API. Obviously this service has nothing to do directly with shipping, as it simply calculates tax based on a user's address (technically, the Zip+4, which is returned by the USPS lookup). I am not sure what agreement TaxCloud has with USPS, but this seems like a good workaround for those looking for address verification for the purpose of calculating sales/use tax.

Comment: Matt SmartyStreets & LiveAddress are operated by same company...same website layout and pricing model,also both are NOT FREE. to me it looks like your post is more about promoting your company then assisting with the code.

Answer (score -1):

The Service Objects address validation web service can determine if an address is valid according to the USPS. Below are a couple of C# examples (RESTful request and SOAP request):

Restful request

```
string mainURL = "https://trial.serviceobjects.com/AV3/api.svc/GetBestMatchesJson/" + businessName + "/" + address + "/" + address2 + "/" + city + "/" + state + "/" + zip + "/" + licenseKey;
AV3Response result = null;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(mainURL ) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Timeout = 5000;//timeout for get operation
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
 if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
 throw new Exception(String.Format(
 "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
 response.StatusCode,
 response.StatusDescription));
 //parse response
 DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AV3Response));
 object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
 result = objResponse as AV3Response;
//processing result
if (result.error == null)
{
 //process result
}
else
{
 //process error
}
```

The other option is to consume the wsdl and make a SOAP request.

SOAP request

```
//Add a service to your application https://trial.serviceobjects.com/av3/api.svc/
AV3Client_Primary = new AddressValidation3Client("DOTSAddressValidation3");
response = AV3Client_Primary.GetBestMatches(Business, Address, Address2, City, State, PostalCode, licenseKey);
```

The response field will contain information about the validity of the address. The DPV score can be used to determine if an address is deliverable, non deliverable, or is close to correct but missing some vital piece of information (apt, ste, rr #).

[DPV Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZjay.png)

If you'd like more in depth information on the service's outputs you can check out [here](https://docs.serviceobjects.com/display/devguide/DOTS+Address+Validation+-+US+3?ZUT=5049958)