# Validation on an entire Class MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Currently i have a customer class that the user can partially create, and finish the detailed information down the line.  For example it looks like this

**New Customer**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Business name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Business Name:")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address:")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State:")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Zip:")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
```

**Customer Checkout**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Business name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Business Name:")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Address:")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "City:")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "State:")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Zip is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Zip:")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }
```

when the user goes to checkout i need to make sure that they do finish filling out the information if some is missing. 
My thought process was to create a Customer Checkout class populated with the information from when they created a new customer and check to see if its valid before passing them along to checkout.  My issue is the only way i know to do that is to check each field against string.isNullOrEmpty() but i know there has to be a better way.  I will have to check 25 fields like this.  I know that you can check if a Model is valid, but i need to do this at a class level in my Data Access Layer checking to make sure all[required] fields have data.  Hopefully i am just overlooking something

almost like I need some way to do something like

```
bool hasErrors = false 

foreach attribute in my class 
if it is marked as [required]
check to make sure not null or empty
if it is set hasErrors = true
```

thanks!

Comment: are you looking for "how to validate addresses"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049958/how-to-validate-the-given-address-using-usps

Comment: no sorry, i am looking how to validate a class without having to check all 25 fields for is null or empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **performance is not a consideration** you can use reflection to automatically validate your object.

```
static class ObjectValidator
{
    public static bool IsValid(object toValidate)
    {
        Type type = toValidate.GetType();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach(var propInfo in properties)
        {
            var required = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), false);
            if (required.Length > 0)
            {
                var value = propInfo.GetValue(toValidate, null);
                // Here you'll need to expand the tests if you want for types like string
                if (value == default(propInfo.PropertyType))
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom validation for your model,

Implements the interface `IValidatableObject` and override the implement the method `Validate` and create your custom validation for example

```
public class Foo : IValidatableObject
{

      public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
      {
          //make your custom rules for validation on server side
        if ((fooAttribute== true) && (fooAtribute2 == String.Empty))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Your custom Error");
        }
      }

}
```

`NOTE:` **With this you're achieving validation on the server side of your application**

Comment: Why is it that everyone that suggests IValidateableObject conveniently neglects to mention that it doesn't do client-side validation?  This is an important aspect to how the site functions if you mix client-side and server-side-only validation.  By neglecting to mention this you do a serious disservice to those you are trying to help, because then they will likely not understand why their validaiton workflow is insane.

Comment: but in the example code I put in comment form that ths code is for server side validations... I mean, could be more clear I know but i mentioned in the answer...

Comment: my issue is that in the end its really not much different than what i am doing now.  Instead of a custom validator i have a method that will check each of the 25 fields.  I am just curious if there is a way to validate a class, instead of model using the [Required] attribute that i already defined in my constructor.

Comment: Not that I know, with the approach that i'm answering you could handle the error and use the method ModelState.IsValid without called to a specific method to validate and the error catched will be automatic render when you needed in your view, base in the `ValidationMessageFor` of your view